# GitHub Action with Concurrency

Tags: github, github-actions

My query is for the example given here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency

Example: Using a fallback value

I understood how concurrency works. But this example for the fallback value is not clear to me.

> If you build the group name with a property that is only defined for specific events, you can use a fallback value. For example, `github.head_ref` is only defined on `pull_request` events. If your workflow responds to other events in addition to `pull_request` events, you will need to provide a fallback to avoid a syntax error. The following concurrency group cancels in-progress jobs or runs on pull_request events only; if `github.head_ref` is undefined, the concurrency group will fallback to the run ID, which is guaranteed to be both unique and defined for the run.

```yaml
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.head_ref || github.run_id }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

Can someone please explain this part "**if `github.head_ref` is undefined**"?

Comment: Which part is not clear from this example? Could you please highlight that?

Comment: "if github.head_ref is undefined,". In what case, the branch reference will be undetermined?

Comment: [`github.head_ref`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) will be undefined if the event is other than `pull_request` or `pull_request_target`.

Comment: [`github.head_ref`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context): "**The `head_ref` or source branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either `pull_request` or `pull_request_target`.**"

Comment: Thank you, @Azeem. Your input has clarified it.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could be of help. You might want to add that part "**if `github.head_ref` is undefined**" to your question to make it clear for other readers about the confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this expression:

```yaml
github.head_ref || github.run_id
```

`github.head_ref` may not be available.

According to [`github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context):

> `github.head_ref`
>
> "The `head_ref` or source branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either `pull_request` or `pull_request_target`."

So, `github.head_ref` is only defined for `pull_request` or `pull_request_target` and where it is undefined the fallback mechanism will be the `github.run_id`.

Comment: Yes, I reproduced the above scenario in my test workflow yaml. When an event is not triggered by a PR event and the concurrency group is head_ref. It will give a syntax error. To handle other workflow-triggering events, use a fallback ```github.run_id``` to avoid a syntax error.